# rearranging words with regex and add space conditional

Tags: r, regex

I am reformatting a string with `regex` in `r` and I am trying to remove a space in case a word is not found.

```
sub('^log2\\.Ratio\\.(.)\\.(.)\\.(normalized)?.*', 
    'log2(\\3 Ratio \\1/\\2)', 
    c('log2.Ratio.M.L.normalized.for','log2.Ratio.M.L.rev'))
```

The result works in general, but I get an extra space in case the word `normalized` isn't found.

```
"log2(normalized Ratio M/L)" "log2( Ratio M/L)"
```

Has anyone an idea how to make the space behind `\\3` conditional?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

R regexes do not support  conditional replacement strings  (like Boost, e.g. you may use conditional replacement in Notepad++). However, you may use `gsubfn` and use a custom replacement logic in the callback part:

```
library(gsubfn)
x <- c('log2.Ratio.M.L.normalized.for','log2.Ratio.M.L.rev')
rx <- '^log2\\.Ratio\\.(.)\\.(.)\\.(normalized)?.*'
gsubfn(rx, function(x, y, z) 
    ifelse(nchar(z)>0, 
    paste0("log2(",z," Ratio ",x,"/",y, ")"),
    paste0("log2(Ratio ",x,"/",y,")")),
    x)
## => [1] "log2(normalized Ratio M/L)" "log2(Ratio M/L)"
```

Here:

- `ifelse(nchar(z)>0` - checks if Group 3 (`normalized`) is matched
- `paste0("log2(",z," Ratio ",x,"/",y, ")")` - if yes, use `'log2(\\3 Ratio \\1/\\2)'`
- `paste0("log2(Ratio ",x,"/",y,")")` - else, use `'log2(Ratio \\1/\\2)'` replacement scheme.

The `x` stands for `\\1`, `y` for `\\2` and `z` for `\\3`.

Comment: Ok, this was actually what I was thinking, that regex can not do these conditional strings. Your solution looks great, but might be a bit overkill for my problem :-) But I will definitely keep `gsubfn` in mind.

Comment: @drmariod: Once you need to manipulate `\1`, `\2` or `\3`, you will have to rely on `gsubfn`. Also, if you have larger strings where nothing can be harcoded, `gsubfn` will also be of much help. akrun's approach is a work around, mine is a general solution.

Comment: u r right, so I changed the solved flag to you answer, I guess akrun will not be to unhappy by loosing some points :-) I think in my solution I will still go with my nested `sub` command since it is just easier to read. But I said, the `gsubfn` is awesome and gives a lot possibilities. Is it actually also working with more than 9 variables?

Comment: Well, please accept the answer that *works best for you*. I did not post my comment to convince you to change your mind, that is just my opinion. As for the number of backreferences, no, only the default 1 to 9 are supported. If you define more, the ID of the capturing group is output only. Well, there is another way to handle this if you want to use more than 9 groups.

Answer (score 1):

We could `paste` the `log2(` substring

```
paste0("log2(", trimws(sub("^log2\\.Ratio\\.(.)\\.(.)\\.*(normalized)?.*", 
          "\\3 Ratio \\1/\\2)", str1)))
#[1] "log2(normalized Ratio M/L)" "log2(Ratio M/L)"
```

Comment: This brought me to the idea to use `sub('\\( ', '(',...` But I wasn't aware of the `trimws` function... Thanks!